# do you need a Noether ring for Noetherian Theorem?

Tags: ring-theory

just wondering if a Noetherian ring has any relation to the conservation law of Noether's Theorem?  I thought I read the universal enveloping algebra can fall under a Noetherian ring, and was wondering if a Noetherian ring implies Noether's Theorem?

Comment: There is no relation, other than being invented by the same woman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are just both eponymously named after the same person, [Emmy Noether](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmy_noether).

Noether's theorem is couched mostly in terms of mathematical physics, and is a statement about symmetries on a space evolving according to some Lagrangian. While a Noetherian ring might be found while doing Lagrangian mechanics, they are not vital to the statement of Noether's theorem.

There is a nifty little book by Neuenschwander called [*Emmy Noether's Wonderful Theorem*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004FV4N94) which I found to be very accessable.

By the way, when seeing other things named "Noether," you might want to be on your guard: Emmy's father was a productive mathematician as well as her :) See [this, for example.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Noether%27s_theorem)

There is a footnote in T.Y. Lam's *Lectures on Modules and rings* about the Lasker-Noether theorem on primary decomposition of modules (p 102):

> The Lasker-Noether Theorem was originally named after the chess master and mathematician Emanuel Lasker and Emmy's father, Max Noether. The version of this theorem for a commutative Noetherian ring should perhaps be more appropriately called the "Lasker-Noether-Noether Theorem". Incidentally, Noether herself never knew that the rings satisfying her Endlichkeitsbedingung ["finiteness condition," referring to the ascending chain condition] were to be christened Noetherian rings. This term was coined by Claude Chevalley only in 1943; Emmy died in 1935...

Comment: Hey, thanks!!!!  Great forum, think I'll be posting a lot this summer :)  Glad I asked!

Comment: Ah, thank you for pointing that out!